# Обмен с БД Java паттерн DAO

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, dao

Реализую Java-приложение, которое общается с БД - вывод данных на экран, insert, update, delete.

Из простых сущностей есть таблица *tags*, которая содержит: *id, name, color, order_num*.

Как я понял паттерн DAO, то я должен сделать следующее:

1. *interface TagsDao*
2. В интерфейсе определить методы: *insert, update, select* (будут содержать непосредственно выполнение SQL-запросов к БД через JDBC)
3. *class Tag implements TagsDao* c переменными *id, name, color, order_num*
4. Для того, чтобы получить все тэги, то в интерфейсе мне также нужно определить метод *get* с запросом
   *SELECT id, name, color, order_num FROM tags;* который возвращает List < Tag > allTags и с этим *allTags* работать уже в Java.
5. Когда я что-то делаю с какой-то переменной класса *Tag* в приложении, то я одновременно обращаюсь к методу DAO и обновляю сущность в БД.

Правильно ли я понял паттерн DAO для работы с БД в моём случае?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что Вы описали, это стандартный механизм использования DAO. Единственная оговорка:

> Для того, чтобы получить все тэги, то в интерфейсе мне также нужно
> определить метод get с запросом SELECT id, name, color, order_num FROM
> tags; который возвращает List < Tag > allTags и с этим allTags
> работать уже в Java.

Совсем необязательно выбирать из БД всё. Можно использовать отбор с помощью того же `WHERE` Более того выборку всех данных имеет смысл делать, если она действительно нужна (даже для общих списков используют частичную выборку данных с пагинацией), т.к. данных может быть очень много и их получение и обработка может быть очень затратной операцией.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! В конкретной таблице мне надо получить именно все записи, много их там быть не может изначально. Про условие WHERE понятно. Я сомневался в том, что вообще правильно понял способ вывода данных из БД, для того, чтобы потом их использовать в приложении.